# Calculating running sum starting x years before

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sum

I have a table with entity name, year and activity number as
bellow. During some years there is not any activity.

```
name | year | act_num
-----+------+---------
aa   | 2000 |       2
aa   | 2001 |       6
aa   | 2002 |       9
aa   | 2003 |      15
aa   | 2005 |      17
b    | 2000 |       3
b    | 2002 |       4
b    | 2003 |       9
b    | 2005 |      12
b    | 2006 |       2
```

To create it on postgresql;

```
CREATE TABLE entity_year_activity (
name character varying(10),
year integer,
act_num integer
);

INSERT INTO entity_year_activity
VALUES
    ('aa', 2000, 2),
    ('aa', 2001, 6),
    ('aa', 2002, 9),
    ('aa', 2003, 15),
    ('aa', 2005, 17),
    ('b', 2000, 3),
    ('b', 2002, 4),
    ('b', 2003, 9),
    ('b', 2005, 12),
    ('b', 2006, 2);
```

I would like to have the total number of the past x years with the
number of this year activities for each entity for every year as bellow.

As an example for x = three years.

```
name | year | act_num | total_3_years
-----+------+---------+---------------
aa   | 2000 |       2 |      2
aa   | 2001 |       6 |      8
aa   | 2002 |       9 |     17
aa   | 2003 |      15 |     30
aa   | 2004 |       0 |     24
aa   | 2005 |      17 |     32
b    | 2000 |       3 |      3
b    | 2001 |       0 |      3
b    | 2002 |       4 |      7
b    | 2003 |       9 |     13
b    | 2005 |      12 |     21
b    | 2006 |       2 |     14
```

Comment: Great question. Sample data, expected output, DDL. It's worth noting that Stack Overflow doesn't preserve tabs, though, so your `COPY` output got mangled. Better to use `COPY ... CSV`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach that uses the ability to use the `sum` aggregate as a window function with a range-based window frame - see `SUM(...) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY year ROWS 2 PRECEDING)` and [window framing](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html).

```
WITH name_years(gen_name, gen_year) AS (
  SELECT gen_name, s
  FROM generate_series(
    (SELECT min(year) FROM entity_year_activity),
    (SELECT max(year) FROM entity_year_activity)
  ) s CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM entity_year_activity) n(gen_name)
),
windowed_history(name, year,act_num,last3_actnum) AS (
  SELECT
    gen_name, gen_year, coalesce( act_num, 0),
    SUM(coalesce(act_num,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY gen_name ORDER BY gen_year ROWS 2 PRECEDING)
  FROM name_years 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN entity_year_activity ON (gen_name = name AND gen_year = year)
)
SELECT name, year, act_num, sum(last3_actnum) as total_3_years
FROM windowed_history
GROUP BY name, year, act_num
HAVING sum(last3_actnum) <> 0
ORDER BY name, year;
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/e4b69/1).

The need to generate entries for years that have no entry themselves complicates this query. I generate a table of all (name, year) pairs, then `left outer join entity_year_activity` on it before doing the window sum, so all years for all name sets are represented. That's why this is so complicated. Then I filter the aggregated result to exclude entries with zero in the sum.

Comment: This also doesn't skip the missing year, so it is not correct.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ... hence "yet".

Answer (score 3):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/28f29/4)

```
select
    s.name,
    d "year",
    coalesce(act_num, 0) act_num,
    coalesce(act_num, 0)
    + lag(coalesce(act_num, 0), 1, 0) over(partition by s.name order by d)
    + lag(coalesce(act_num, 0), 2, 0) over(partition by s.name order by d)
    total_3_years
from
    entity_year_activity eya
    right join (
        generate_series(
            (select min("year") from entity_year_activity),
            (select max("year") from entity_year_activity)
        ) d cross join (
        select distinct name
        from entity_year_activity
        ) f
    ) s on s.name = eya.name and s.d = eya."year"
order by s.name, d
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because it does not skip years with no data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff New version does.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT en_key.name, en_key.year, en_key.act_num, SUM(en_sum.act_num) as total_3_years
FROM entity_year_activity en_key
  INNER JOIN entity_year_activity en_sum
     ON en_key.name = en_sum.name
WHERE en_sum.year BETWEEN en_key.year - 2 AND en_key.year
GROUP BY en_key.name, en_key.year
```

Comment: If you fix this by moving the `where` clause into the `on` clause and removing `en_key.year = en_sum.year`, then it will work.

Comment: Edited to remove the en_key.year = en_sum.year.  That does defeat the purpose.  I'm not sure if the where clause needs to be moved to the on clause.  I think it would work either way.  Stylistically, I didn't see it as part of the join, but rather a condition on the report.  I expect it is a matter of opinion and preference.

Comment: . . As a general practice, join conditions should go in the `on` clause, so aethetically it belongs there rather than in the `where` clause.  However, the performance of the two versions should be the same.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm saying it's not a join condition, it's a regular where condition.  Or rather that if it is a join condition or not is an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Another try. This one lacks the 0 row years, though:

```
select t1.name, t1.year, t1.act_num,
      (select sum(t2.act_num) from entity_year_activity t2
                              where t2.year between t1.year - 2 and t1.year
                                    and t2.name = t1.name) total
from entity_year_activity t1;
```